# Concatenate a single database field's multiple values

Tags: crystal-reports, concatenation

I have a report that brings in values from a stored procedure. I want to use some of those values as part of the report's Header title.

I'm trying to find a way to take each of the 2 to 5 distinct values from the Database Field "Distrib" and concatenate them to make the title, separated by spaces and commas, when necessary.

If I were to do this in C#, I would use a foreach and print out each value, but I see no such functionality in Crystal Reports.

How may I concatenate each value in an individual database field? FWIW, that field is currently used to populate a row in a cross-table. I thought to access that cross-table field, as well, but I don't see how it's possible from within a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a formula, named 'push', add it to the Detail section, suppress it, then add the following to its text:

```
//{@push}
//build an array of unique string values

//force formula to execute during first pass (before grouping and totaling is done)
WhileReadingRecords;  

//create a string array
Stringvar Array items;

//change {table.field} to an appropriate value
items := Array_Push(items, {table.field});

//can't return an array, so use a dummy value
true;
```

Create a formula named 'serialize', add it to the Report Header section, then add the following to its text:

```
//{@serialize}
//create comma-delimited list

//force evaluation to occur during second pass
WhilePrintingRecords;  

//declare array
Stringvar Array items;

//serialize array
Join(items, ",");
```

This solution relies on two custom functions that I built: [Array_Push()](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2008/01/09/crystal-reports-array_push-function/) and [Array_Contains()](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2008/01/09/crystal-reports-array_contains-function/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Craig. If these formulas rely on your functions, do I also need those functions somewhere?

Comment: Well, I added the custom functions - that was not difficult - but I'm getting this error when I attempt to add Push formula to the details section :

Comment: "This Field Name is not known", then it highlights {table.Distrib} as the unknown field name.

Comment: Jon, you need to substitute your actual field name for {table.Distrib}.  I was making an example.

Comment: Okay, I see you were indicating the table.Distrib refers to the <tableName>.Distrib, and I've corrected that to be the actual table name (stored procedure name, actually). However, NOW I get a real error: "**the result of a formula cannot be an array**".

What else can I do?

Comment: I added a line to the {@push} formula.

Comment: No errors or warnings with this, but also no values returned to either the {@Push} nor {@Serialize} formulas.

I wish I knew this stuff better so I could audit the logic myself

Comment: When I browse data for the new formulas, I get nothing in the window - does this mean I'm connecting the {@Push} formula wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is related to the evaluation times of the formulae and the report header.  When my workstation is working, I'll take a look at the approach.  You could move the logic a subreport located in Report Header section; the subreport will be evaluated before the Report Header.

Comment: I see, so move all new functions and formulas to the sub-report, and embed the sub-report in the header... I'll give it a whirl

Comment: I made a change to the {@serialize} function (see edit).  It will work as expected and without a subreport.

Comment: Okay! Looking good! This is the answer. How does the Serialize formula know where to look for the array of strings?

Comment: 'Stringvar' declares a variable of global (main report) scope.  You could be explicit and write Global Stringvar Array item if you want.  a Shared variable can be referenced in the main reports and its subreports.

Comment: Radical. Thanks much for your assistance and patience. :)